# Unable to load DLL 'MklImports': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, ml.net, microsoft.ml

```
[DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'MklImports': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)]
```

Microsoft.ML.Transforms.TimeSeries.EigenUtils.Dsytrd(Layout matrixLayout, Uplo uplo, Int32 n, Double[] a, Int32 lda, Double[] d, Double[] e, Double[] tau) +0
Microsoft.ML.Transforms.TimeSeries.EigenUtils.MklSymmetricEigenDecomposition(Single[] input, Int32 size, Single[]& eigenValues, Single[]& eigenVectors) +336
Microsoft.ML.Transforms.TimeSeries.TrajectoryMatrix.ComputeSvd(Single[]& singularValues, Single[]& leftSingularvectors) +131
Microsoft.ML.Transforms.TimeSeries.AdaptiveSingularSpectrumSequenceModelerInternal.TrainCore(Single[] dataArray, Int32 originalSeriesLength) +134
Microsoft.ML.Transforms.TimeSeries.AdaptiveSingularSpectrumSequenceModelerInternal.Train(RoleMappedData data) +676
Microsoft.ML.Transforms.TimeSeries.SsaForecastingTransformer..ctor(IHostEnvironment env, Options options, IDataView input) +130
Microsoft.ML.Transforms.TimeSeries.SsaForecastingEstimator.Fit(IDataView input) +57
PredictionTestAplication.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\Users\HP\source\repos\PredictionTestAplication\PredictionTestAplication\Controllers\HomeController.cs:81
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +61
System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__11_0() +50
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.b__2() +228
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__3() +35
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9850389
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

I am getting This issue in MVC5 asp.net in ML.net Please help if any one face this issue before Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue, I got crazy a couple of days.

The things that solved the issue were the following:

1. Check if the VC vcredist_x64 for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019, and 2022 is installed. You can find it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170
2. Check if the Java Open JDK 11.2 is installed and the BIN path is in the path environment table. In the end I installed microsoft-jdk-11.0.21-windows-x64 from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/download
3. Check if the application pool is running in 32 bit mode. If yes, just disable the option in the IIS Manager.

Have a good day, Michele